Unable to open Partner Telephony contact centers in Salesforce Service cloud voice-setup
I am getting below error while navigating to Partner telephony Contact Centers. However, I am able create new contact centers through Partner Telephony setup section.
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: 1617106196)
An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 592864686-284700 (1617106196)

Does this answer your question? Internal Server Error - What's in a GACK?
